# Macbook M1 losing WiFi after short power outage

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, apple-silicon

When I'm outside I usually work with my Macbook, which is at home, through AnyDesk. I have a situation that when there are very short power outages at home, I lose my connection because Macbook M1 cannot access the network, even though it is connected to the WiFi router.

It's strange because every other device at home, (TVs, tablets and even Echo Dot,) just reestablish the connection seamlessly.

The only way I can recover internet access on my Macbook is restarting it. And, because I'm outside home I lose my AnyDesk connection until I get home. I'm running latest macOS Big Sur 11.4.

Comment: Have you made sure auto reconnect is on for that wifi? If it is, it's probably a bug. You may be able to circumvent it by repositioning your MacBook near your router and using ethernet. It's also common that wifi won't auto-reconnect far away from the router and a manual reconnect is required.

Comment: Yes, it's turned on. WiFi router is 3 meters away.

Comment: Does Ethernet fix the issue? I assume it would not be too hard to move your MacBook and charger to the router since your only 3 meters away.

Comment: I've not tried it yet because macbook m1 has no Ethernet port. Anyway there would be an Ethernet cable crossing the living room :/

Comment: Oh I assumed you had a dongle. I really don’t know in that case. Maybe switch from 2,4 network to 5 gz network or vice versa?